# Generic use of 2 same classes but from different packages

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

I have two same model classes,but they are in different packages.
First one is: `model.my.prod.Model` and second `model.my.test.Model`

I have also a simple mapper for this `model.my.prod.Model` which take a `Model` class as a parameter:

```
public class Mapper{

    private static Map<Model, String> models= new HashMap<>();

    static {
        models.put(Model.IMAGE_JPG, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        models.put(Model.IMAGE_GIF, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE);
    }

    public static String createModelMap(Model model) {
        if (models.containsKey(model)) {
            return models.get(model);
        } else {
            throw new ModelException("Exeception");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use this `Mapper` also for `model.my.test.Model`, is it possible without copy of this `Mapper` and change a `Model` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Object and explicit casting(when necessary)

```
public class Mapper{

    // private static Map<Model, String> models= new HashMap<>();        
    private static Map<Object, String> models= new HashMap<>();

    static {
        models.put(Model.IMAGE_JPG, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        models.put(Model.IMAGE_GIF, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE);
    }

    // public static String createModelMap(Model model) {
    public static String createModelMap(Object model) {
        if (models.containsKey(model)) {
            return models.get(model);
        } else {
            throw new ModelException("Exeception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use full qualified class names. It will make your code ugly, but you will be able to use to Model classes in Mapper.

So, instead of

```
    public static String createModelMap(Model model)
```

you will have two methods

```
    public static String createModelMap(model.my.prod.Model model) 
    public static String createModelMap(model.my.test.Model model)
```

In additional I can suggest you to rename both classes with different and more meaningful names.
And, also it's a bad idea to have packages for production and testing classes, you can use default maven/gradle project structures to avoid such packages

[image]

Comment: It is a solution, but I think it is connected with duplicate code of `createModelMap` function.